# Unable to connect to quickbooks

Tags: .net, vb.net, quickbooks, qbxml

I am trying to build a vb application that can add invoice to QuickBooks.
But i am having trouble in starting the connection to QBs at start.

I download and install a QuickBooks Premier 2012-13, but using Trial version.
I also download the QuickBooks SDK 12.0.

However, when i start testing the connection with QuickBooks with QuickBooks open.
I got this error message:
COMException was unhandled
The requested connection type could not be found.

Here is what I got in code:

> Dim strTicket As String
>
> Dim qbxmlcom As New QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2
>
> qbxmlcom.OpenConnection2("", "Testing App", QBXMLRP2Lib.QBXMLRPConnectionType.localQBD)
>
> strTicket = qbxmlcom.BeginSession("", QBXMLRP2Lib.QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare)

I having no idea what i got wrong. Is there any setting I missed?
I even try to use SDKTestPlus3 to test the connection, it got the same error message.

Can anyone give me some idea of what i got wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have Quickbooks launched with a company file open, otherwise you need to provide the path to the file in qbxmlcom.BeginSession("{Company File Here}", QBXMLRP2Lib.QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare)

Answer (score 1):

While [this article](http://www.rfcons.com/index.php?id=70&tx_knowledgebase_pi1%5Bcmd%5D=kb_viewOneArticle&tx_knowledgebase_pi1%5Buid%5D=51&cHash=98016056a3) refers to Time Tracker, I believe it may be supportive of your question.

Note specifically the following words (emphasis mine):

> QuickBooks Free Edition, QuickBooks Simple Start ***and similar*** might not
>   work by design. ***This is a technical limitation imposed by Intuit*** on
>   their product suite, completely independent of TimeTTracker MX2, QBE.
>   Please contact Intuit in order to confirm whether your particular
>   QuickBooks edition is ***supposed to include third-party application
>   integration (qbXML) capabilities***

It sounds as though Intuit has a policy in place of enabling/disabling integration features based on the specific edition. If they have crippled the Premier Trial in such a way, this would explain your COMException.